# Save the current user when saving a model in Django admin backend

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-authentication

I'd like to store the user that saved a model for the first time in one of the fields of that model. This is what I have.

`models.py`:

```
from django.conf import settings
class Project(models.Model):
[...]
    added_by = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.PROTECT)

    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        if not obj.pk:
            obj.added_by = request.user
        super().save_model(request, obj, form, change)
```

`settings.py`:

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'auth.User'
```

The `request.user` appears to be always empty (I'm logged in as root to the `/admin`). What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does not belong in the *model*, but in the `ModelAdmin`:

```
from django.contrib import admin


@admin.register(ModelAdmin)
class ProjectAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    # …

    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        if obj._state.adding:
            obj.added_by = request.user
        return super().save_model(request, obj, form, change)
```